# How to convert double array to image in Java ro save as image?

Tags: java, arrays, image, image-processing

I have an arary of double value (or can be float values as well). The range of the values are between 0-255. The array is in shape of [128][128][3], thus a RGB array of image. Now I want save this array as image (png or jpg). How this can be done in Java?

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28671344 - you'll have to convert the doubles to bytes...

Comment: Or a way that gives more control - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4845770

Comment: I checked them but they do not answer my question. Here, I have an array already with float values. The shape of the array is [128][128][3]. The 3 indicates the channel for image (Red, Green and Blue). The values range from 0 to 255. I wonder if there is an in-built function or easier way to convert the array to an image?

Comment: The second answer gives the clue .. see [WritableRaster javadoc] (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html#setSamples(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20double[])) - or `setPixels` which lets you set an area to your values.  There doesn't seem to be a "do it from your array" (unless you can make it work with one of the [SampleModels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/SampleModel.html) like in this previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15005373/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I could understand the image in Java.

after having an array of `int[][][] nwimage = new int[128][128][3]`, convert all values from the float array to integer. The float array has shape of [128][128][3] as well.

now create a buffered image with the shape of `nwimage` as 2D which is 128x128.

```
BufferedImage bfImage = new BufferedImage(128, 128, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

now setRGB for each index of the `bfImage` as below;

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 128; j++) {
            Color myRGB = new Color(nwimage[i][j][0], nwimage[i][j][1], nwimage[i][j][2]);
            int rgb = myRGB.getRGB();
            bfImage.setRGB(i, j, rgb);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's possible to create new `Color`s from `float` arguments too, so you don't need to convert your array to integer first. But in any case, you'll end up with an integer based image. Float/double based `BufferedImage`s are also possible. 

Comment: Thanks for the point. I figured it out after posting the answer. Thanks again to put a note to the answer.